# What sources of information are there to find suitable congress, reunions, convention and other scientific gathering events?

Tags: conference

I started a PhD in bioinformatics last year, changing my previous (undergrad) research topic from genetic engineering / virology  to chemoinformatics / neglected diseases. I've already went to a few congresses related to my field, but I'm not sure I'm aware of everything that is out there.

Back in my previous lab, various senior scientists would suggest me different conferences, but I'm the only one here working in chemoinformatics and my professor is rather new to the area too.

Is there any source of information to rapidly find scientific conferences? I'm having a hard time to find good ones about chemoinformatics

Suggestions?

Comment: Major professional societies often compile "calendars" or other lists of upcoming conferences and events throughout the discipline.  So check the website or newsletter of the main professional societies that cover your research area.

Comment: Every meeting has a slightly different flavor which is largely determined by its usual organizers and attendees. Take a look at the CVs of people in the field and see where they have provided lectures. Note which meetings co-occur with the same group of names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search at the [CORE conference ranking website](http://portal.core.edu.au/) produces the following:

Tier A:

- IEEE Computational Systems Bioinformatics Conference (CSB) <sup><sub>[can't find a link! WikiCFP seems to think it hasn't been held in a while either]</sub></sup>

Tier B:

- Asia-Pacific Bioinformatics Conference (APBC) [Perennial website](http://homepage.cs.latrobe.edu.au/ypchen/APBChomepage.htm)
- Workshop on Algorithms in Bioinformatics (WABI) [2018 website](http://algo2018.hiit.fi/wabi/)

Tier C:

- Bioinformatics Visualization (BioVis) [2018 website](http://biovis.net/2018/index.html)
- IEEE Bioinformatics and Bioengineering (BIBE) [2018 website](http://bibe2018.asia.edu.tw/)
- IEEE Symposium on Computational Intelligence in Bioinformatics and Computational Biology (CIBCB) [2018 website](http://cibcb.org/CIBCB2018/)

An alternative venue for searching for relevant conferences is [WikiCFP](http://wikicfp.com), which gathers Calls-For-Papers of a great many conferences.